# View passando data para Model em formato errado

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5, datetime, globalização

Estou usando `Bootstrap-Datapicker` como campo de data em meu formulário e globalizando com `moment-with-locales`.

A configuração que usei é a seguinte:

```
$('.datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    locale: 'pt-br',
    format: 'L'
});
```

O formato `L` é `DD/MM/YYYY` dentro do `moment-with-locales.js`:

```
longDateFormat : {
    LT : 'HH:mm',
    LTS : 'LT:ss',
    L : 'DD/MM/YYYY',
    LL : 'D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY',
    LLL : 'D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY [às] LT',
    LLLL : 'dddd, D [de] MMMM [de] YYYY [às] LT'
},
```

Mas quando escolho uma data ela é passada para o formato `MM/dd/yyyy` assim que é enviada para a model:

[image: Escolhendo a data 02/11/2015]

[image: Debugando o model]

[image: Formato que volta para a View]

A configuração da propriedade na minha model:

```
[DataType(DataType.Date)]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]
public DateTime? DataInicio { get; set; }
```

E estou usando configuração de globalização em meu `web.config`:

```
<system.web>
  <globalization uiCulture="pt-BR" culture="pt-BR" />
  <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5.2" />
  <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5.2" />
</system.web>
```

E finalmente meu field na View:

```
<div class="input-group date datetimepicker" id="datetimepicker1">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="DataInicio" placeholder="Data Inicial" value="@Model.DataInicio" />
    <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
    </span>
</div>
```

E só como observação, eu sei que poderia usar o `Razor` para gerar meu form, mas ainda estou aprendendo e me sinto mais a vontade com `Html`, por enquanto.

Comment: Tente retirar `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:yyyy-MM-dd}")]` ou mude para `[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true, DataFormatString = "{0:dd-MM-yyyy}")]` `

Comment: Já havia tentado ambas as possibilidades antes de postar @Randrade. Esqueci de dizer isso na pergunta, desculpe.

Answer (score 1):

Opa, partindo do princípio que você terá mais models com data, vale a pena você criar um ModelBinder customizável para seus DateTime que por ventura serão bindados da View ao Model.

```
public class DateTimeModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        #region Fields


        private readonly string _customFormat;

        #endregion

        #region Constructors and Destructors

       public DateTimeModelBinder(string customFormat)
        {
            this._customFormat = customFormat;
        }

        #endregion

        #region Explicit Interface Methods

        object IModelBinder.BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            ValueProviderResult value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
            return DateTime.ParseExact(value.AttemptedValue, this._customFormat, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
        }

        #endregion
    }
```

Em seguida você registra seu novo DateTimeModelBinder no seu **Global.asx**

```
ModelBinders.Binders[typeof(DateTime)] = 
           new DateAndTimeModelBinder() { CustomFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd" };
```

Me parece que não precisará da configuração de globalization no seu web.config.

Esse artigo do Scott pode te ajudar. http://www.hanselman.com/blog/SplittingDateTimeUnitTestingASPNETMVCCustomModelBinders.aspx